# Simpler way to get the list of words that has only 1 letter difference? (python)

Tags: python

```
words = []

for w in wordList:
    wcnt = 0
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if w[i] != word[i]:
            wcnt += 1
    if wcnt == 1:
        words.append(w)
```

Given a word and a list of strings, I want to retrieve the list of strings that has only one character different from the given `word`.

I tried the code above, and it works fine, but it takes too long.

I am practicing an interview, and I prefer not to use any library.

How can I make it simpler?

example)
`word = "lost"`

`wordList= ["most","mist","miss","lost","fist","fish"]`

Output should be `['most']`

EDIT: only changing 1 character works. Not deleting or adding.

Comment: By different you just mean "changed to another character", right?  So `last` and `blast` are not off by one character, and neither are `sap` and `asp`.

Comment: @Dawn17 What about ABCD and BXCD, SAP and PAS, SAP and ASP? Can u answer for these 3 inputs?

Comment: the provided code (which OP said it worked) hints that characters are compared with their current positions only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The complexity would remain the same, but maybe you could speed it up using `sum` inside a list comprehension:

```
words = [w for w in wordList if sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(word,w)) == 1]
```

- `zip` avoids playing with indices by directly interleaving letters and yielding them for one to one comparison
- `sum` avoids counting natively in python (the expression interleaves letters of both words and adds 1 if different, 0 otherwise, comparison yields `True` or `False` which are worth 1 and 0 respectively)
- list comprehensions are highly optimized python constructs
- the code above doesn't use any external libraries, only built-ins
- it doesn't crash with `IndexError` even if the length of the words differ (even if the results will then be unreliable) because `zip` stops when the shorter sequence ends.
- one-liners are cool (when not too far-fetched/with side effects)

so the more builtins you'll use, the faster it will generally get. Here it could probably be slightly improved to stop counting if the number of different letters reaches 2, but it would mean stop using comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Comment: You don't need to stop using comprehensions when the threshold is one: `if any(a != b ...)`

Comment: yes, but it's already in my answer: "sum avoids counting natively in python (the expression interleaves letters of both words and adds 1 if different, 0 otherwise, comparison yields True or False which are worth 1 and 0 respectively)". Is there a point you want clarified more?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre to support  words of different length, I would use `len(word) == len(w) and sum(a!=b for a,b in zip(word,w)) == 1`. The `and` shortcircuiting might even make it faster if some words have different length

Answer (score 2):

How about using a built-in library (`difflib`)?

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

word = "lost"
wordList= ["most", "mist", "miss", "lost", "fist", "fish"]


>>> [x for x in wordList 
     if SequenceMatcher(None, word, x).ratio() == (len(word) - 1) / float(len(word))]
['most']
```

Comment: "I am practicing an interview, and I prefer not to use any library.". But that said, it's a good answer for those who don't practise interviews.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Levenstein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

You can directly use it in python with the **Natural Language Toolkit**:

```
import nltk
nltk.edit_distance('asdff','asdfe')
```

This will return **1**, since the distance of the word is 1, which means one letter is different.

Comment: Not the DV, but OP said:"only changing 1 character works. Not deleting or adding." Levenshtein Distance counts insertions and deletions.